# url redirecting using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need your help to make some url redirection using .htaccess
The case is that I have url like www.website.com/index.php?chID=1234 which opens particular tv channel on the website.
The problem is that I want to make these urls like www.website.com/channel-name/1234 (where 1234 is that chID variable, to get record from the database, of course without it would be more nice).
here is the working link - http://www.livepage.info/world-tv-channels.php?chID=1512

any suggestion will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect all channels, you could use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/\d+)/$ http://www.livepage.info/$1 [L,R=302,QSA]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(\d+)$ index.php?chID=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Don't forget that you will need a new HEAD tag in your HTML (otherwise images will be fetched from `http://www.livepage.info/euronews-russia/images/...`):

```html
<base href="http://www.livepage.info/">
```

Of course, you could use .htaccess instead. This is, however, not as good as the `base href` tag, since the client wouldn't use the cache when viewing different channels, or if the client gets redirected, will need two requests for each image etc.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(images|folder2|folder3)(/.+)$ $2$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^channel-name/(\d+)/?$ index.php?chID=$1 [L]
```

This will redirect URLs in the format `channel-name/chID` with an optional trailing slash to the raw URL you provided. `chID` must be 1 or more digits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I've tried but it doesn't work fine, i don't know why.. I've putted this: 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^euronews-russia/(\d+)/?$ world-tv-channels.php?chID=$1 [L]


please take a look here - 
http://www.livepage.info/euronews-russia/1512/ 

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: P.S. there are few channels beginning with name 'euronews' like 
'euronews','euronews france', 'euronews espanol','euronews russia',etc.

Comment: You may need to escape the `-`. Try `^euronews\-russia/(\d+)/?$`