# how to rediect form htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect from `http://www.example.com/index.php?abz_xyz` to `http://www.example.com/abz_xyz` with `htaccess`. I am using this code on my htaccess file `Redirect /index.php?abz_xyz http://www.example.com/abz_xyz/` but this is not working kindly please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [url redirecting using .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063598/url-redirecting-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (my regex may be off)
The [L] means Last, so once the rewrite engine hits that line, it'll redirect immediately if it matches

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?abz_xyz$ /abz_xyz/ [L]
```